# Why does the toggle function not work as expected?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascript and I started with a simple task of writing a small script.. Where I was expecting the string to be displayed effected by the toggle button click...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<button onclick="foo()">Foo</button>
<button onclick="toggle()">Toogle</button>
<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
     var toggle = false;//set the desired initial value to toggle flag
     var x = "";

     function toggle() {
         alert("ENTERED Toggle");
         toggle = !toggle;
         x= toggle? "Toggle set to true. " : "";
     }

     function foo() {`enter code here`
         alert("ENTERED Foo");
         var y = "Food pressed";
         y = x + y;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=y; // display the x value
     }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Expected: when only foo is clicked alert box is shown and clicking on 'OK' just the plain "Foo pressed." should be displayed. When clicked on toggle once and then foo is clicked then "Toggle set to true. Foo pressed" {two alerts occur in this process} is to be displayed and again the Toggle is pressed for second time and foo is pressed the toggle flag is toggles and only "Foo pressed." is displayed and it follows so.....

Actual result: only foo click works and toggle click doesn't work at all.

can some one shed some light on this ?

Comment: Did you ask the browser's debugger yet? - F12 for IE, Ctrl-Shift-I for FF, Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Please learn [how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Answer (score 2):

You have clashing names. The `toggle` function replaces the `toggle` variable. This is because in ECMAScript (Javascript) a function can be passed around by not adding the parentheses, which is to say that functions are [first-class citizen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen).

An example on this:

```
x = alert; //"x" is now the same function as "alert"
x("Hej");
```

Your definition of the `toggle` function is therefore equivalent to this assignment:

```
var toggle = function() {
  alert("ENTERED Toggle");
  toggle = !toggle;
  x= toggle? "Toggle set to true. " : "";
}
```

The solution is to give either the function or the variable another name.

Comment: Vikstrom: thank you very much. it works now. I didn't knew that I cannot have a function and a variable with same name...